# Is there some option to create Yii2 ActiveDataProvider from query and static data?

Tags: php, yii2

I use ActiveDataProvider to display some data using GridView. Also I have some data retrieved from API and this is a array. For example:

```
$emails = [
    '123' => 'john@test.io',
    '234' => 'jane@test.io',
    '345' => 'jake@test.io'
];
$query = new Query();
$query->select(['id', 'username'])->from('user');
$provider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
       'pageSize' => 100,
    ],
]);
```

Result of displaying this ActiveDataProvider will be something like this:

```
+------+--------------+
|  id  |    username  |
+------+--------------+
| 123  | John         |
| 234  | Jane         |
| 345  | Jake         |
+------+--------------+
```

How can I join data from query and array to get something like this:

```
+------+--------------+-------------------+
|  id  |    username  |        email      |
+------+--------------+-------------------+
| 123  | John         | john@test.io      |
| 234  | Jane         | jane@test.io      |
| 345  | Jake         | jake@test.io      |
+------+--------------+-------------------+
```

I found the only one option - create an array from query and merge it with existing array, but it looks bad for me. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for this
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider

An ArrayDataProvider acts in a lot of the ways the same as an ActiveDataProvider and you can use it as the base data for most of the Yii2 controls. I would get the ActiveDataProvider data, parse it, match it to what you already have by default and create an array that can be used as the base of the ArrayDataProvider.

If you are putting it into a DataGrid you can always do something like this for the email column

```
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
        'attribute' => 'email',
        'format'=>'raw',
        'value'=>function ($model) use ($emails) {
            return $emails[$model->id];
        },
    ],
```

Comment: I know what ArrayDataProvider is, issue is "How to join data from array to query", not "How to display array in GridView". Convert query into array and join it thru foreach is litle bit expensive.

Comment: You can always just get the data like this $recordsArray = $query->select(['id', 'username'])->from('user')->asArray()->all(); and bypass the ArrayDataProvider. However you are losing on pagination and other things that the ArrayDataProvider is doing. If you really want to use the ArrayDataProvider then you are already retrieving the data, getting it into models etc, going through it is the least of your bottleneck.

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to do with it? can't you just use the ActiveDataProvider and merge the result with your array content? What is the use case for this?

Comment: If you are putting it into a DataGrid you can always do something like this for the email column
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
                'attribute' => 'email',
                'format'=>'raw',
                'value'=>function ($model) use($emails) {
                    return $emails[$model->id];
                },
            ],

Comment: Data stores in 3 different databases. I have direct access only for one of them, other two only using of their servers API.

Comment: That is ok, but what are you finally doing with the data? Showing it on screen, file download, etc?

Comment: Display on screen

Comment: See the edit to my answer. You can do that to get it on screen. That code is part of a GridView column definition.

Comment: It have more sence. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

A way , for complex or aggregated  model, could be based on adding  and afterFind method in your model
add the property you need and populate you value with a proper function eg:named getYourRelatedEmail()
or you could use an assigment depending the way you obatin the email array or the related values)

In your model

```
    public $userEmail;  

    public function afterFind()
      {
        $this->userEmail = getYourRelatedEmail();
      }
```

in this way you can acces in gridview  to the model data field as  common model field

In this way you could retrive all the data you need form different sources  and build yuor composite model as you need ..